# can't test ember component that appends a div to the dom

Tags: ember-qunit, ember-testing, ember-cli-addons

I have a ember-cli-addon that adds a component which appends a div with a specific class to the consuming application. I'm trying to test this integration and having difficulty to setup the test.

I have tried to unit test the component as well but that doesn't work quite as expected. Here's what I've tried:

I've copied the component from my `addon` directory to `tests/dummy/components/jquery-backstretch.js` to make it available to the dummy test application:

**jquery-backstretch.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'jquery-backstretch',
  image: null,
  selector: 'body',
  fade: 0,
  duration: 5000,
  centeredX: true,
  centeredY: true,

  setupJquerybackstretch: function() {
    var image = this.get('image');
    if (! Ember.isEmpty(image)) {
      var options = {
        fade: this.get('fade'),
        centeredX: this.get('centeredX'),
        centeredY: this.get('centeredY')
      };

      var jqbsImage;
      if (Ember.typeOf(image) === 'string') {
        jqbsImage = 'assets/' + image;
      } else if (Ember.isArray(image)) {
        options.duration = this.get('duration');
        jqbsImage = image.map(function(img) {return 'assets/' + img;});
      } else {
        Ember.Logger.error('Ember JQuery-Backstretch: Unsupported "image" format.');
      }

      Ember.$(this.get('selector')).backstretch(jqbsImage, options);
    } else {
      Ember.Logger.error('Ember JQuery-Backstretch: image not supplied.');
    }
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  teardownJquerybackstretch: function() {
    Ember.$(this.get('selector')).backstretch('destroy');
  }.on('willDestroyElement')
});
```

this causes the component to append the img to the `body` of the test page and not to `#ember-testing-container`, changing the `selector` to `#ember-testingn-container` puts the img in the right place but the test can't find it:

**tests/acceptance/jquery-backstretch.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {
  module,
  test
} from 'qunit';
import startApp from '../../tests/helpers/start-app';

var application;

module('Acceptance: JqueryBackstretch', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    // Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});


test('backstretch added to body tag', function(assert) {
  visit('/');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(find('.backstretch > img').length, 1, 'Backstretch found');
  });
});
```

**application.hbs**

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
{{jquery-backstretch image="img/emberjs.png"}}
{{outlet}}
```

the test is not passing, it can't find the image, I also tried to test the component and append it to the DOM then test to see if it's in the DOM but that didn't yield better results.

How can I test this please?

Comment: does it work in browser like this using the built in ember server (from the ember-cli tooling). Curious if this is a test issue or truly a component/render issue

Comment: @ToranBillups I have this backstrech setup as a component in an app, and it seems to work fine. I've taken that component and dropped it into the addon and was trying to test it but I've not tried the half-baked addon though.